# Rename S3 files while copying AWS sdk

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

My Spark job writes the results to one S3 bucket and I need to copy this data to another S3 bucket and rename the files. What kind of regex should I build to be able to rename the files in the needed format?
The path I copy the files from is: `s3://test-bucket/qa/snapshot/processing_time=1385351/id=5721/name=sport/part-e34jt-5a9ghej-fh7r-4710-ghds31o.c000.csv`
The final path I expect to see: `s3://prod-bucket/results/processing_time=1385351/id=5721/sport.csv`

This is how I build the paths currently but I need to adjust this regex to be able to rename the files:

```
val destBasePath = "s3://prod-bucket/results"
val segmentAndNameRx = """s3.*/(\d*/.*csv)""".r

fullSourcePath match {
  case segmentAndNameRx(segmentAndName) => {
    val path = s"${destBasePath.stripSuffix("/")}/$segmentAndName"
    Some(path)
  }
  case _ => None
}
```

fullSourcePath here is the path of each of the files in the source bucket. The example if above. I'm using AWS SDK client in Scala for this/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
processing_time=(\d+)/id=(\d+)/name=([^/]+)
```

It simply matches some numbers and the last part `([^/]+)` anything until `/`. Group 1 will contain `processing_time` digits, group 2 `id` digits and group 3 `name` characters.

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

val fullSourcePath = "s3://test-bucket/qa/snapshot/processing_time=1385351/id=5721/name=sport/part-e34jt-5a9ghej-fh7r-4710-ghds31o.c000.csv"
val destBasePath = "s3://prod-bucket/results"
val segmentAndNameRx: Regex = """processing_time=(\d+)/id=(\d+)/name=([^/]+)""".r

segmentAndNameRx.findFirstMatchIn(fullSourcePath) match {
  case Some(groups) =>
    val path = s"$destBasePath/processing_time=${groups.group(1)}/id=${groups.group(2)}/name=${groups.group(3)}"
    println(path)
  case None =>
    println("Pattern was not matched.")
}
```

You can then use `findFirstMatchIn` to get the matching groups and construct the path based on them.

Note that this will only work if the order is always the same, but in URLs like this it usually is.